How to get custom error pages for different errors in next js 14 App router
I need a custom error page for all validation errors in my app. I made a custom exception for all validation related errors.
export default class ValidationError extends Error {
  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message);
    this.name = "ValidationError";
  }
}

My idea is to throw this exception whenever a required url param is missing, so that only for this error I can show a custom error screen in the error.tsx.
my page.tsx
const Page = async (props: PageProps) => {
  const orderQueryId = props.searchParams["id"];
  if (!orderQueryId) throw new ValidationError("Provide a valid orderId");
}

error.tsx
export type ErrorPageProps = {
  error: Error & { digest?: string };
  reset: () => void;
};

function ErrorPage(errorPageProps: ErrorPageProps) {
  const errorMessage = errorPageProps.error.message;
  if(errorPageProps.error.name === "ValidationError")
       return <p>{errorMessage}</p>
  else return <p>Something went wring</p>

}

This works in all errors thrown in client components but in server components I'm getting the error.name always "Error"
error message in available in both client and server components. The problem is with the error.name.
